# Sitecore's treelist field not getting updated immediately

Tags: sitecore, sitecore8

I am updating sitecore treelist field type through code in background (when RTE is open for the same item) and it is not reflecting with the new values immediately. I had checked both in database and CMS.

After sometime it reflects in the field and the database as well.

Here are few things I checked:

1. Cleared sitecore and browser cache.
2. Added Cachemanager. `Enabled=false` and `Cachemanager.Enabled=true` when updating the item.
3. Checked the eventqueue table if the item save event is called.

Here is the code:

```
           var article = master.GetItem(new ID(data.CurrentItemId));
            if (article != null)
            {
                var referencedValues = article.Fields["Referenced articles"];
                using (new SecurityDisabler())
                {
                    //CacheManager.Enabled = false;
                    article.Editing.BeginEdit();
                    if (referencedValues != null)
                        referencedValues.Value = "{5A3D67DF-3917-4AC2-BDAF-69CDA1204C2A}";                        

                    article.Editing.EndEdit(true);
                    //CacheManager.Enabled = true;
                }
            }
```

Comment: Is it the same item where the RTE is opening and also updating the tree list? Are you making use of workflow?

Comment: Yes, it is the same item which i am editing and updating. The item is part of workflow but i removed the workflow assigned manually from the workflow section of the item to verify if that is causing the issue. But it didnt help.

Comment: So the only reason I see is because you are updating the treelist and saving it while editing in the RTE simultaneously. I would suggest to do it one at a time. Can you please try to do it one at a time and see if the treelist is populated properly